# clipboard.write modifies my links prepending "about:blank"

Tags: javascript, html, email, outlook, clipboard

I'm building a React app to create an html email message that needs to be copied in the clipboard and then sent by Oulook. I'm also trying to build an index with clickable items (I know this won't work in a mobile environment).

if you can run this code (i can't put in a jsFiddle cause the document needs to be focused):

```
const copy = `<div>
      <div><a href="#id1">click here</a></div>
      <div>a</div>
      <div>...</div>
      <div id="id1">a</div>
    </div>`;
    if ('clipboard' in navigator) {
      navigator.clipboard.write([
        new ClipboardItem(
          {
            'text/html': new Blob([copy], { type: 'text/html' }),
          }
        ),
      ]);
    }
```

and then try to paste into an outlook email message (MS Word should do the same), you'll see that the anchor link becomes something like "about:blank#id1", which doesn't work...
Is there any way I can achieve what I'm trying to do?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using "react-copy-to-clipboard" which is not affected by this issue.
I had to face an additional issue on Outlook, as using a "long" id was not working (it was getting truncated)